# JdbcOdbc Driver Failed to Load

Tags: java, jdbc

```
public class DBtest 
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("JDBC-ODBC driver failed to load.");
            return;
         }
     }
}
```

Showing Exception Message

> "JDBC ODBC Driver failed to load"

I have 2 questions 
1-Where This JdbcOdbcDriver can be foud for MS ACCESS ?
2-If MS access Drier option in Administrative tool -> ODBC(64-bit)-> System DSN->Select Driver  indicate the JDBC ODBC driver for connectivity then why it is not connecting

Comment: Did you include the `jdbc` driver in your library? (Are you using an IDE?)

Comment: Which java version you are using?

Comment: yes i did  include jdbc library

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the java version you're using. Supposing you're using the latest JDK, JdbcOdbc driver is [no longer available](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html).

Comment: brother i am using java version 8

Comment: Well, no ODBC then. You can try http://sourceforge.net/projects/ucanaccess/ if you need to read/write .mdb or .accdb files.

Comment: thanks bro . lets check this one :)